# Lyx View action not working (inactive)

Tags: lyx

I have created a very simple document in Lyx and want to preview it. But the "View" action (the one bound to Command+R) and its corresponding tool bar button (with the icon showing two large eyes) are inactive/disabled. Strangely, "View other Format" is working fine, for example for PDF.

I am on Mac OS 10.9 with MacTex 2014 and Lyx 2.1.1 installed. I have already tried to re-compute my configuration (last item in "Tools" menu) and re-install Lyx but "View" remains disabled.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know if it's relevant, but have you selected 'Use non-TeX fonts' (or whatever it's called) in the document settings?

Comment: Indeed! The document option "Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)" was **not** selected initially; after selecting it Command+R works fine now and the corresponding tool bar button is enabled. So this solves the issue. THANKS! But I'm puzzled, why do I have to stop using TeX fonts to make the default "View" action work, even though viewing PDF via the "View other formats" action works fine with both settings???

Comment: I don't really know. Have you made any (other) changes to font-settings in your document? Does the same happen with a new, default, document?

Comment: I haven't changed any document settings. When creating a new document, "Use non-TeX fonts" is again disabled for the new document, at first. But I guess I can change that via button "Save as Document Defaults" for future new documents.

Comment: So the View-button is greyed out also for a new document? What is written behind *View* in the Document-menu? (E.g. *View [PDF (xelatex)]*?

Comment: When the view action is disabled (i.e. when "Use non-TeX fonts" it **not** selected) then there is no item in the Document menu for this action (only for action "View other formats").

Comment: Hm, ok. I don't really know what's going on, maybe scottkosty can shed some light on it, if he sees this. Could be that a default converter is somehow not defined for the view-command, but the 'use non-TeX'-fonts thing will select a specific converter.

Comment: I'm not sure either. The only thing I can think of is that `lualatex` and `xelatex` are in your PATH but not `pdflatex`. Can you run `pdflatex` outside of LyX? Can you post the output of reconfigure (you can see this either if you start LyX from the terminal or go to View > Messages Pane). Actually, can you try starting LyX from the terminal instead and see if you have the same problem? Sometimes different environment variables are set. Also, try backing up and then removing your user directory (find this in the Help > About menu) without LyX running. Then start LyX again.

Comment: Ok, I tried a few things: 1) pdflatex started from command line -> it is in the path 2) start lyx from command line -> problem persists 3) reconfigure -> problem persists 4) deleted user directory .../Libaray/Application Support/Lyx.../ and restarted Lyx -> problem solved! Now the default View action is enabled even without selecting the "Use non-TeX fonts" document property. So it seems some configuration saved in my user directory was messed up. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: btw: when starting Lyx from the command line (before resetting my user directory) I got these error messages: 2014-08-02 08:01:06.234 lyx[6857:507] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Times New Roman" and got font with PostScript name "TimesNewRomanPSMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
2014-08-02 08:01:06.235 lyx[6857:507] CoreText performance note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSuboptimalRequest to debug. (and a few more of these, but too long to post here)

Comment: the output of reconfigure (before resetting my user dir) is too long to post here, but there were no obvious error messages; one excerpt about pdflatex: "07:54:50.093: checking for the pdflatex program...
07:54:50.094: +checking for "pdflatex"...  yes
07:54:50.094: checking for XeTeX...
07:54:50.095: +checking for "xelatex"...  yes
07:54:50.095: checking for LuaTeX...
07:54:50.095: +checking for "lualatex"...  yes
07:54:50.096: checking for LuaTeX (DVI)...
07:54:50.096: +checking for "dvilualatex"...  yes
07:54:52.626: checking if LuaTeX is usable ... yes"

Comment: Glad it was working. Do you still have your old user directory? It would be interesting to see what changed. I've never seen those terminal warnings on Ubuntu so I'm guessing it's a Mac thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not save my old user directory (forgot that it might be useful later for debugging, sorry!). But I have just noticed: the warnings shown when Lyx is started from command line still appear (even though my initial problem with the View action is gone, now). So maybe these warnings can be reproduced with any MacOS X 10.9 installation of Lyx?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a faulty user profile, solved by deleting the profile directory.

Comment: This worked for me. In the menu, Document -> Settings -> Formats -> Default output format -> PDF(pdflatex)

Comment: @Presbitero you should post that as an answer. That fixed it for me.